# Install Spree with rails 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, e-commerce, spree

I've been trying to install spree following instructions on Getting started giude at guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html

```
$ rails 4.1.2 new mystore
$ cd mystore
```

whithout issue. When i run

```
$ spree install --auto-accept
```

I get:

gemfile spree
gemfile spree_gateway
gemfile spree_auth_devise
run bundle install from "."
The git source //github/spree/spree_gateway.git is not yet checked out. Please run bundle install before trying to start your application

I ran

```
:~/mystore$ bundle install

Updating github/spree/spree_gateway.git
Updating github/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from //rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from //rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies..................................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
```

In Gemfile:

```
spree (= 2.3.3) ruby depends on
spree_backend (= 2.3.3) ruby depends on
spree_core (= 2.3.3) ruby depends on
rails (~> 4.1.4) ruby

rails (4.1.2)
```

What have I done wrong in the steps listed in the guides.
Please, how do I resolve these dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rails 4.1.2` isn't the newest version now, docs are outdated and Spree (at least branch you're using) needs newer version, change your command to:

`rails 4.1.5 new mystore` #or `4.1.4` like your error says: `rails (~> 4.1.4) ruby` means at least `4.1.4`

and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I used Rails 4.1.6 instead. I'll now look up how to change database to MySQL because it seems to use sqlite by default.